# incrementing a score in redis sorted sets

Tags: redis

I want to track daily usage statistics using redis's sorted sets in which the score would be the time stamp and the member would be the value of that specific statistic (since I want to use zrange to fetch the statistics)

so if I have a visits key

`zadd "visits", "20131211", 1` # which would add a single visit to the date of today dec 11, 2013

but what happens in the other visits?

How do I increment the score of a member?

I feel may be confusing the purpose of `member` and `score`

Answer (score 3):

There is `ZINCRBY`.

Example from the docs:

```
ZINCRBY visits 1 "20131211"
```

Also, if the member doesn't exist yet, it get's added with the score you passed along. [ZINCRBY in the Redis docs](http://redis.io/commands/zincrby)

Comment: thats where my confusion comes.. zincrby would increment the score of the member.. so in this case, 20131211 is a score or a member? the zadd I wrote above has 20131211 as score

Comment: The order of operands is  `ZINCRBY key increment member`. I'll add the link in the answer. Depending on the binding you use, it might be different.

Comment: if the date is `member`, doing `zrange` would return the date and not the scores

Comment: Aww I get you now. There's no command to increment the member itself instead of the score, if you want to stick with that architecture you will have to do it manually by querying it first, then setting the new value. In that case you will have to take care of the atomicity in your stoftware.

Comment: How would you suggest that it is better doing it?

Comment: The easiest would propably be to increment a key, for example `stats:visits:20131211`. You can then, in your application, loop over the dates you want to query and generate a `MULTI` query for redis. If you use a nice binding, you'll be returned an array or list or whatever you can then reduce by adding the returned values together, ignoring these with a value of NIL (keys that don't exist)

Comment: @MildlyInteresting is right. Be careful with your statistics stored in the zset: if they are exactly the same you will lose data as redis will update the score of this particular value and not inserting a 'new' one. Add a UUID to your zset value to be sure there is no collision, could be the timestamp for instance (it is the score and a value of your zset value).